# How do I parse json objects so that I can get all the values correctly

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

So I got this JSON string which looks like this:

```
{"success":false,"errors":[{"name":["Username &quot;admin&quot; has already been taken."],"email":["Email is not a valid email address."]}],"data":[]}
```

or, more readably:

```
{
  "success": false,
  "errors": [
    {
      "name": [
        "Username &quot;admin&quot; has already been taken."
      ],
      "email": [
        "Email is not a valid email address."
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": []
}
```

And I want to parse it in a way where I can get all the items in "errors" no matter the name of the error or value. Because the objects inside "errors" aren't always going to be "name" and "email" there might be different ones, but they will always be structured like that.

I managed to get this far:

```
var theObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(theJsonString);
```

And the goal would be to make it into a dictionary where I could get the name and the value of the error. Or just the name and value as one string would also work.

Essentially getting a collection of all the errors.

UPDATE

I tried deserializing it into it's own object

```
var theObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(responseString);
```

Where the model looks like this

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("errors")]
    //public Error[] Errors { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("errors")]
    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public object[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Which then throws this error

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]'
> because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to
> deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to
> a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized
> type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface
> (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a
> JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force
> it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath 'errors', line 1,
> position 27."}

Comment: a Dictionary is likely to be your friend here, as you've mentioned. What's the difficulty, exactly?

Comment: You need a class with a property "errors" like so: `public Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors {get; set;}`

Comment: @Fildor I don't quite understand

Comment: Fildor means, instead of deserialising to JObject, make your own class deserialise to that class (a bit like in the example here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) and have that as one of the properties.

Comment: @ADyson Oh! Yeah I tried that and I got an exception, I added it to the updated version of this question

Comment: I think `errors` should be `public List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>> errors { get; set; }`.  It's an array of objects where the objects' property values are arrays of strings, so you should expect two levels of `List<T>`.  (Formatting the JSON makes that easier to see.  You can use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or https://jsonlint.com/ to do that online.)

Comment: What dbc said. Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/2dUJod . The dictionary deserialises a single object and lists all of that object's properties, so you need a list of dictionaries to account for the fact that errors is an array.

Comment: Take a look at your JSON.  The `errors` object is a collection, the first object in it is an object with name and email properties, each of which is a collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors is a `List<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>`
It looks like this:

```
"errors": [ <--
    {
      "1": [
        "Username &quot;admin&quot; has already been taken."
      ],
      "2": [
        "Email is not a valid email address."
      ]
    }
] <--
,
```

not a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` that will llok like :

```
"errors": 
    {
      "1": [
        "Username &quot;admin&quot; has already been taken."
      ],
      "2": [
        "Email is not a valid email address."
      ]
    },
```

Answer (score -2):

A easy solutution for you would be:

If u have Visual Studio open it.

1. Copy ur Json Code.
2. Click on this and it generate your Code automatically for you :)
   [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMngK.png)

Edit -> Import Json

Good Luck! :)
Sometimes it can be happen that he choose a "false" Datatype, but on ur litte json u will be fine.

This would be the output:

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public Error[] errors { get; set; }
        public object[] data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Error
    {
        public string[] name { get; set; }
        public string[] email { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: OP specifically said that the contents of errors will not always be "name" and "email". Sometimes there will be different properties. That was the whole point of the question. So simply hard-coding the property names isn't correct.